# How to compute Soft Absolute Function in a numerically stable way?

Tags: numerical-methods

I want to evaluate $$f(x) = x \frac{\exp(ax)+\exp(-ax)}{\exp(ax)-\exp(-ax)}$$

This is a function approximate absolute value of $x$. However,as $a$ goes to large, the better approximation it gets. But this leads to numerical overflow as it will be an exponential function of something big

Any trick to avoid this ?

Comment: For large positive $ax$ you can rewrite the ratio as $\frac{1+\exp(-2ax)}{1-\exp(-2ax)}$. Similar for large negative $ax$. Alternatively, you can try just evaluating $\tanh(ax)$ in another way entirely, for example by using its series at $\pm \infty$.

Comment: For positive values of $x$, divide numerator and denominator by $exp(ax)$. For negative $x$ multiply both numerator and denominator by $exp(ax)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Try $\sqrt{x^2+\epsilon^2}-\epsilon$.